# minima function is positive defined

Tags: maxima-minima, positive-definite

Is a function: C(x, y) = min(x, y) a positive definite function?

I think it is not positive - a defined function. If values x and y are negative the f (x, y) <0

Comment: When asking a question you should properly define your terms. So why don't you start by spelling out in detail what "positive definite function" means. Maybe this already helps to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you mean $C(x,x)\geq 0$ with equality iff $x=0$, then certainly it isn't positive definite. Pick $x=-1$ then you habe $C(x,x)=-1<0$ a contradiction.

Comment: You recognised yourself that the OP did not properly define his terms. It is much better to ask him for clarification istead of providing a (trivial?) answer based on some (arbitrary?) assumption what he may have meant.